# Angular, Unable to find the root parent by its class interface

Tags: angular, parent-child, angular14, angular-providers, angular-dependency-injection

From the angular documentation [here](https://angular.io/guide/dependency-injection-navtree#find-a-parent-by-its-class-interface), I had created a Parent class using

```
export abstract class Parent {}
```

Inside the AlexComponent, I had provided this component as Parent  to its children

```
providers: [{ provide: Parent, useExisting: forwardRef(() => AlexComponent) }]
```

Im able to access the parent inside the child component using

```
export class CarolComponent {
   name = 'Carol';
   constructor( @Optional() public parent?: Parent ) { }
}
```

But I am unable to access the parent inside the nested child components. That means parent provider gives the immediate Parent but I want to access the root parent.

For example, In this screenshot,

[image]

I want the Chris component to access the Alice Component (root parent but not immediate parent)

Is there a way to access the root parent ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've created an example in stackblitz and it works. I don't know if it's what you want to do. The child component `Chris` access root parent `Alice` injecting the `Parent` class.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-accessing-root-parent

Comment: I had tried a similar approach and it worked for me. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Components are created and injected into your application through Angular's injector.

Each Angular element that is decorated (@Component, @Service, ...) gets an injection token corresponding to the class itself, which is then pushed into a weakMap.

This means that every Angular element should be injected into another element and should be used by this element, provided that they are in the same injector and that they are injected and used in a correct order.

What happens here for you, is that you probably extends the Parent class in the Alice component, but also in the "blue" classes. Since the weakMap relies on the class metadata to work, it probably erases the Alice component from the weakMap to replace it with your blue class.

To resolve that, try not extending the Parent class, and reference directly your classes instead of an abstract class. See if it works.